# Django - How does Django access data in sqlite?

Tags: django, postgresql, sqlite, connection, database-connection

How does Django access data in sqlite database?

**Lets assume this scenario:**

Very basic `models.py`, and `views.py` are created to accept user input from page and store it in `sqlite` database. If a user clicks a submit button, that data is sent to `sqlite` database, and the user can view it by accessing the `Django Admin` page. Later the user wants to display the stored data using CBV in `views.py`:

```
class Some_ListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'some_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'SomeInfo'
    model = models.SomeModel
```

And the data in the database is rendered in `HTML` like this:

```
{% for item in SomeInfo %}
  <p>item<p>
{% endfor %}
```

When & how does Django load data when rendering a page? Does it access & retrieve data whenever a any html page is loaded? Is there any way to load data in a previous page, temporarily store it, and inject it in a future page? How do you get connection? Does it use connection pool?

I will be using PostgreSQL for database for my real project, and I'm looking for advice on when & how to establish connection using connection pool.

**Another scenario:**

Some data were prepared by creating Class `WellInfo` in `models.py`. You can view this data in `Django Admin` page:

[image]

Using these data, I was able to make a list page using `ListView` like this:

[image]

Upon clicking any of the row, user will be navigated to a page that renders that object instance's data. So if a user clicks `University Well`, user will reach a page that has data relevant only to `University Well`. And I did so without explicitly telling Django to use only that object. I only set up primary key url using `api`. How did Django know to display only `University Well`'s data, but not the others?

Comment: pass the data item as a dictionary to the template through view.py and use the keys inside **{{ }}** to get its value

Comment: These sources may help you. 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/databases/
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26470158/django-1-7-and-connection-pooling-to-postgresql
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-concurrency-and-database-connections

I currently use a Django Multi-tenant application with Postgres on Heroku. Heroku has its only limitations in terms of connections with postgres. I have yet to see a negative effect.